# cannot access opencv.org

Tags: opencv

I just heard from my friend that open 3.0 is out.

I want to try this but I cannot access http://opencv.org/.

It says :

---

> Coming soon: Another fine website hosted by WebFaction.
>   Site not configured
>
> If you are the owner of this website and weren’t expecting to see this message, here are some potential causes and solutions:
>
> You recently created a new website record, but opened the URL before your changes were activated in the web server and DNS configuration. Wait a moment and refresh.
>       You created a new website record without the current subdomain (for example, www). Return to the control panel to add the current subdomain to the website record and refresh.
>       You added a new domain in the control panel but didn’t create a site record to link it with an application. Create a website record with the control panel and refresh.
>       Your website record is set for HTTPS, but you visited a HTTP URL (or vice-versa). Open the URL with the other protocol.
>       You tried to access your website by IP address. Access the website by domain name instead.
>       There is a problem with your account. Check the control panel for unresolved support tickets and check your email for recent messages from support@webfaction.com.
>
> For more details, please see Error: Site not configured.

---

I'm sure that I'm not blocked because I use a vpn service.

Comment: haha it's the first time I actually see somebody ask a question like that in 5 years.

Comment: Again, I have the same error when visiting https://docs.opencv.org (and the HTTPS certificate is broken as well)

Answer (score 0):

there was some kind of attack, but only the the main site is down.

if you wanted the src: https://github.com/itseez/opencv

(win)binaries: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/?source=directory

QA: http://answers.opencv.org/questions/

DOCS: http://docs.opencv.org/

Answer (score 0):

[The site was hacked](http://answers.opencv.org/question/45479/main-opencv-website-not-loading/), and they are trying to restore it (according to Alexander Shishkov).

[OpenCV DevZone](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki) ([code.opencv.org](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki)) is still up.

**UPDATE**: It's now back online.